# How create Java Array from Json Array

Tags: java, arrays

Hi Have This Json data in database table

```
["Travellers \u0026 Trekkers","Fitness Freaks","Parenting Group","Sports Lovers","Work: Startups","Art, Music \u0026 Literature","Volunteer Activities","Movie, Food \u0026 Events"]
```

How i use it in java. or how make a java array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you should look to integrating a pre-written, open-source library that parses the JSON for you. I would recommend [json-simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple) from Google, or org.json library.